# CSS3 Portfolio Animation

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I build a HTML-Portfolio for my own. The problem is that the animation does not run smooth.

Have a look on my Page: http://www.predatordesign.de/demo (Scroll Down to the Portfolio Section). Sometimes a border (or something like that) appears between my "portfolio-items" (screenshots below).

My Fullcode: **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wcy9h8rx/)**

```css
.portfolio-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.portfolio-container .portfolio-item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.portfolio-container .portfolio-item img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    overflow: hidden
}

.portfolio-container .portfolio-item span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.portfolio-container .portfolio-item:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.portfolio-container .portfolio-item:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-wrapper content-wrapper">
          <div class="portfolio-container">
              <div class="portfolio-item">
                  <a href="#">
                      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/800x800">
                      <span>Dies ist nur ein Test</span>
                  </a>
              </div>
              <div class="portfolio-item">
                  <a href="#">
                      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/800x800">
                      <span>Dies ist nur ein Test</span>
                  </a>
              </div>
              <div class="portfolio-item">
                  <a href="#">
                      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/800x800">
                      <span>Dies ist nur ein Test</span>
                  </a>
              </div>
              <div class="portfolio-item">
                  <a href="#">
                      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/800x800">
                      <span>Dies ist nur ein Test</span>
                  </a>
              </div>
              <div class="portfolio-item">
                  <a href="#">
                      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/800x800">
                      <span>Dies ist nur ein Test</span>
                  </a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

**Screenshot (gif)**

[image]

Comment: i cant see any border when that happen ?

Comment: Have a look on the GIF :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that would be a fix i just added

```
*{outline: none;}
```

and it should be fixed

here's an example https://jsfiddle.net/dyaa/wcy9h8rx/1/

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work for me. The background appears furthermore :(

Answer (score -1):

It's a chrome issue. It is not the border which is showing up. It is the black background color showing when you are hover the elements.
Try, removing scale property from image. It will solve the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this does not solve the problem. I got the Problem with all popular browsers like Firefox or Safari.